# Jquery get change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've the following code:

```
<script>
function GetDetails(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("EditRecord","TeamPlans")" + "/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#hfId').val(response.ActivityPlanId);
            $('#txtActivityPlanName').val(response.ActivityPlanName);
            $("#CountryId").val(response.OrganizationNumber);
            $('#StateId').val(response.Assignee);
            $('#modal-Update').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Then I also have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CountryId").change(function () {
        $.get("@Url.Action("GetStateList","TeamPlans")", { sOId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
            //$("#StateId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.PositionNumber + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
```

My question is, how can I execute the second script on first script before the modal-update show? `#CountryId` already filled when execute the `url: "@Url.Action("EditRecord","TeamPlans")" + "/" + id,`

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumption your button to show detail has class .detail, you can bind `ajaxStart` to .detail button as

```
$(".detail").ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#CountryId").change(function () {
        $.get("@Url.Action("GetStateList","TeamPlans")", { sOId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
            //$("#StateId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.PositionNumber + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
})
```

More at https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/